# TCP Hole Punching Не удаётся установить соединение

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, winsock, winsock2

Реализую алгоритм создания прямого соединения между двумя клиентами, которые могут находиться за NAT, посредством TCP Hole Punching. Использую интерфейс WinSock2 на C++.

После обмена внешними адресами через сервер, клиенты закрывают соединение (вызовы `shutdown` с флагом `SD_BOTH` и `closesocket`) и пытаются создать новое подключение напрямую (сокеты привязываются к используемым ранее портам). Далее происходит обмен данными.

В случае успеха лог TCP-пакетов выглядит примерно следующим образом:

[image: рис. 1]

Тестирование я провожу в домашней сети, при этом оба клиента запущены на одной машине. Думаю, что для корректной реализации разницы быть не должно.

**192.168.153.196:52023** - Клиент 1, **192.168.153.196:51722** - Клиент 2.
На скриншоте можно видеть, что SYN-сегмент отправленный Клиентом 1 был успешно доставлен до Клиента 2, далее следуют ACK-сегменты и начинается обмен данными через роутер. В данном случае мы имеет такой тип NAT, при котором внутренний порт = внешний порт (то есть например Клиент 1 обращается в публичную сеть так же с порта 52023).

Рассмотрим следующий лог, когда клиенты не смогли установить соединение друг с другом:

[image: рис. 2]

**192.168.1.106:52478** - Клиент 1, **192.168.1.106:52477** - Клиент 2. Далее в логе следует череда повторных отправок SYN-сегментов, пока клиенты не убедятся, что установить соединение не получится. По всей видимости сопоставление в NAT в данном случае создано не было. Здесь уже другой тип NAT - внутренний порт не соответствует внешнему; клиенты так же запущены на одной машине.

Вот ещё 1 неудачный пример, но уже в сети из первого примера (**192.168.153.196:51640** - Клиент 1, **192.168.153.196:51639** - Клиент 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае роутер почему то сбрасывает соединения, как я понимаю.

**Вопрос** что я делаю не так? Каждому клиенту известен верный внешний адрес другого клиента, через небольшой таймаут после закрытия соединения с сервером они в примерно одинаковый момент времени пытаются создать соединение друг с другом со старых портов (вызов `connect`), но роутер либо сбрасывает соединение, либо запись в NAT не создаётся.

---

Есть ещё один странный момент. После установки соединения через, как максимум, пару минут с начала обмена, происходит следующая ситуация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее следует несколько безуспешных попыток переотправки - пакеты как будто игнорируются роутером и не пересылаются. При этом вызов `send` не показывает ошибки, а `recv` на принимающей стороне просто блокируется, так как не видит данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный метод работает не со всеми типами NAT, поскольку их поведение не стандартизировано. Когда два хоста подключаются друг к другу через исходящие соединения, они находятся в состоянии одновременного открытия TCP соединения, при этом должны выполняться условия:

> For the TCP simultaneous open to work, the NAT should:
>
> - not send an RST as a response to an incoming SYN packet that is not part of any
> - mapping accept an incoming SYN for a public endpoint when  the NAT has previously seen an outgoing SYN for the same endpoint
>
> This is enough to guarantee that NATs behave nicely with respect to the TCP simultaneous open.